# Associate interfaces with classes without source access

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

Here's the problem, I have two drawing JAR libraries (A and B). Both provide separate but useful functionality. However, in their infinite wisdom they have two different concepts of the basic point class.

Neither has any interesting or particularly unique methods or fields and both basically boil down to:

```
public class PointA{
   double x;
   double y;
}
```

and

```
public class PointB{
   double x;
   double y;
}
```

The functions in these libraries have methods that look like:

```
public static List<PointA> doInterestingThing();
```

or

```
public static PointB calculateThatThing();
```

I feel like there should be some nice way to just understand that these two classes are for all intents, the same.

If I had source access I could just have them implement some IPoint interface, but both libraries are in JARS.

The way I see it, there are several options:

1. **Convert one to the other**. Either make functions to convert all PointA's to PointB's or vice versa. That would mean essentially making a abstraction layer atop one of the libraries by wrapping every function in it with some boilerplate conversion code.

   ```
   public static List<PointA>doInterestingThingWrapper(){
       return convertPoints(LibraryB.doInterestingThing()); 
   }
   ```
2. **Make some third class** PointC, that both library's results are converted to which represented my code's understanding of a point. Same problems as above, but now I need to write two times as many boilerplate conversions!
3. **Edit the JARS directly**. Obviously this is not preferable. However, it would allow me make PointA and PointB implement the same interface.
4. **Some magic dynamic interface interaction** I don't know about.
   Could it be that Java has some way of dynamically assigning interfaces to already loaded classes?

Something like:

```
public interface IPoint{
   double getX();
   double getY();
}

public static void main(){
    //Magical made up linking syntax
    PointA implements IPoint{
        public getX(){
           this.getX()//PointA's method
        }
        public getY(){
           this.getY(){//pointA's method
        }
    }
    //And same for pointB

    //And now we can say things like:
    List<? extends IPoint> listOPoints=A.doInterestingThing();
    //and:
    IPoint thePoint=B.calculateThatThing();  
}
```

I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate. I didn't even know what to call the problem which makes searching hard. If there's some obvious design pattern (adapter pattern?) that I missed that solves this, let me know.

Comment: How are you using `PointA` and `PointB` in your code? If those classes are mostly used for the external API calls, then there isn't much point in trying to create an abstraction layer because those APIs cannot use it. I.e. what problem are you trying to solve with your suggestions?

Comment: Currently I have a `PointC` type, which I convert everything to and from. I suppose you have a good point (haha) that if most of the functions in A or B take in their own points ie `doInterestingThing(PointA point)` then you'll always have to convert them. If only the libraries had defined and used their own interfaces, I could have pointC implement IPointA and could use them straight in the API calls without converting.

Comment: I think that `PointC` (or just your own `Point`) would be useful, if you can create a _facade_ layer on top of the external APIs, isolating the interactions with those libraries there. Then you could have your codebase depend only on that "facade service" that exposes a single definition of "point".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two solutions

Use reflection and unreflection to use same named functionatily.

Wrap both in your project code into a object that implements the interface.

Sample:

```
class A { public void d(){}}
class B { public void d(){}}
interface D { void d(); }
class AD extends A implements D {}
class BD extends B implements D {}
```

Or

```
class AD implements D {A obj = new A(); public void d(){obj.d();}}
```